# Nhibernate - Using a column value in QueryOver.IsLike

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I need to execute a query that looks roughly like this in SQL:

```
select * from Codes where Value1 like '%' + Value2 + '%'
```

Is there a way to do it using FluentNHibernate and `QueryOver`? I was looking for something like this

```
Session.Query<Code>().WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Value1).IsLike(c => c.Value2);
```

but unfortunately `IsLike` requires an `object` or a `string` value as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested you could use a SQL criterion. I'd put it in an extension method though so it's a bit more reusable if it's something you find yourself using every so often. Something like this...

```
    public static IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> WhereLike<TRoot, TSubType>(this IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> query, Expression<Func<TSubType, object>> thisLike, Expression<Func<TSubType, object>> likeThis)
    {
        var propName1 = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(thisLike.Body);
        var propName2 = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(likeThis.Body);
        query.Where(NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Sql(string.Format(" {0} LIKE '%' + {1} + '%' ", propName1, propName2)));
        return query;
    }
```

Use like so

```
            var query = session.QueryOver<Code>()
                .WhereLike(thisLike => thisLike.Value1, likeThis => likeThis.Value2);
```

Comment: Only thing, I would probably replace the two `, object` with `, string`

Comment: Yep, this works and it is good enough for my case. But it's not the best solution to use in real apps. The generated SQL is not database-independent, and it doesn't work for complex queries (for example, if the query contains columns with identical names from different tables). It seems weird that NHibernate doesn't provide such simple functionality out of the box

Answer (score 2):

One way here would be to use just a raw SQL Criterion:

```
Session
    .Query<Code>()
    //.WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Value1).IsLike(c => c.Value2);
    .Where(Expression.Sql(" Value1Column LIKE '%' + Value2Column + '%' "));
```

It represents the raw SQL, so we have to use column names, not mapped properties here... But for exceptional scenarios like this, this is the NHibernate extension point